# ASP.NET MVC Array of Children Foreign key Non-Nullable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So I have 2 Models setup like this:

```
class Job { ... List<Restriction> userRestrictions {set; get; ... }
```

2nd Model:

```
Restriction { public int Id { get; set; } ... public int JobID { get; set; } }
```

Now, when I edit a job, I fetch the Restrictions via:

```
job = db.Jobs.Where(i => i.Id == id).Include(r => r.UserRestrictions).First();
```

So I iterate through UserRestrictions and manually make them:

```
        @for (ind = 0; ind < Model.UserRestrictions.Count; ind++)
        {
            JaASv1.Models.Restriction p = Model.UserRestrictions[ind];
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="UserRestrictions[@(Counter + ind)].Id" value="@p.Id" />
                <input type="hidden" name="UserRestrictions[@(Counter + ind)].JobId" value="@Model.Id" />
            </td>
```

My Post Method:

```
            public ActionResult Edit(Job job, string ProjTypeOther, string VenderOther, string FoldingOther, string BindingOther)
            ...
            db.Entry(job).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ...
            for (int iter = iterStart; iter >= 0; iter--)
            {
                Restriction r = job.UserRestrictions[iter];

                db.Entry(r).State = EntityState.Modified;

                if (r.Permissions == 0)
                {
                    DelPermission(sPath, r.AdName); // Folder Permission things
                    job.UserRestrictions.Remove(r);

                    continue;

                }
                else if (r.Permissions == 1 )
                {
                    AddPermission(sPath, r.AdName, readRights); // Folder Permission things
                }
                else if (r.Permissions == 2)
                {
                    AddPermission(sPath, r.AdName, writeRights); // Folder Permission things
                }



            }

            db.SaveChanges();
```

I get the following error on db.SaveChanges():

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the
>   foreign-key properties is non-nullable.

I look through all the job.UserRestrictions and see they all have their JobID posted, I even looked in the database context and saw that there aren't any Foreign Keys with NULLs in them, so I don't know what this error is talking about.

Am I perhaps doing something wrong?

I've tried setting each Restriction state to Modified. That didn't seem to work.

I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the actual code that your program gives error.

Comment: ok, the error itself happens on db.SaveChanges(); but I'll show what I do with the post object that comes in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I ended up doing is the following:

Pulling all the UserRestrictions currently in the database.

Upon iterating through the post data, I check for the corresponding item in the database. I also set the UserRestrictions from the Post object to null so ASP doesn't try to re-insert into the table.

If the item doesn't exist, I add the item into the database.

I modify the item from the database instead of the post data one.

I had hoped ASP.NET would handle everything for me, but I guess I can't expect it to do it all.

```
List<Restriction> fromDB = db.Restrictions.Where(r => r.JobId == job.Id).ToList();
List<Restriction> newPost = job.UserRestrictions;
job.UserRestrictions = null;
for (int iter = iterStart; iter >= 0; iter--) {
... // Logic to handle post item
    Restriction b;
    try
    {

         b = fromDB.Where(f => f.Id == r.Id).First();
     }
     catch (Exception er)
     {
         // No record exists yet
         b = r;
         db.Restrictions.Add(b);
      }
      // Modify values of b to the values from post data
    }
  db.SaveChanges();
```

Sorry for strange indentation, StackOverflow should use bbcode instead of whitespace :x